# JSON object not passing as param to webApi PUT method

Tags: angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I’m using Angularjs and asp.net mvc 5 with webApi2.

I’m having some trouble calling a custom PUT method. I’ve done some studying for the past few days, and although I have a decent feel for the situation, I can’t get my JSON object to pass as a parameter for some reason.

Route template:

```
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
```

Web api controller and model (shortened for brevity):

```
public class AttModel
{
    public string dc { get; set; }
    public string dt { get; set; }
}

[HttpPut]
public IHttpActionResult PutAttendRecord([FromBody]AttModel model)
{
    string dc = model.dc;
    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(model.dt);
        
    var record = (from tbl in db.attend_am_y1
                 where tbl.dc_number == dc && tbl.class_date_am == dt
                 select tbl).SingleOrDefault(); 

    record.status_am = "z";
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Javascript object (angularjs PUT):

```
$scope.updateRecord = function () {
        
    var stuInfo = {
        dc: $scope.student.dc,
        dt: $scope.student.dt
    };

    $http.put("/api/attendance/PutAttendRecord/" + stuInfo)
        .then(function (d) {
            alert(d.data.dc_number);
        });
}
```

I tried using Newtonsoft without the extra AttModel class, and passing the param as jObject, but I still get a null value exception within the iHttpActionResult method. The data just isn’t making it to my method. Routing issue?

If I manually place values within these variables in the iHttpActionResult, the method works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are getting into your call alright,
you want to attach your object in the body

```
     $http.put("/api/attendance/PutAttendRecord/", stuInfo)
    .then(function (d) {
        alert(d.data.dc_number);
    });
```

and I don't think you need [FromBody] as I believe this is only specified if the function finds it unclear.